# how to create a virtual file in clang for codecompletion

Tags: c++, autocomplete, clang, llvm, code-completion

Im trying to create virtual files for codecompletion in clang. Unfortunately, my application segfaults.
I have the following setup:

```
auto createVirtualFile = [](
  clang::CompilerInstance& ci,
  std::string name,
  llvm::StringRef input
) {
  std::unique_ptr<llvm::MemoryBuffer>
    MB(llvm::MemoryBuffer::getMemBuffer(input, name));
  return std::move(MB);
};
```

Once the file is created i setup a CodeCompletConsumer:

```
auto setupCodeComplete = [](
  clang::CompilerInstance& ci,
  std::string File,
  int Line,
  int Column
) {
  auto& F = ci.getFrontendOpts();
  F.CodeCompletionAt.FileName = File;
  F.CodeCompletionAt.Line = Line;
  F.CodeCompletionAt.Column = Column;
  clang::FrontendInputFile FrontFile(File, clang::IK_CXX);
  //F.Inputs.push_back(FrontFile);
  ci.createCodeCompletionConsumer();
  return FrontFile;
};
```

I invoke those two functions the following way and execute a syntax only action:

```
auto runCodeCompleteAt = [] (
  clang::CompilerInstance& ci,
  std::string Filename,
  std::string Code,
  int Line,
  int Column
) {
  auto fid = createVirtualFile(ci, Filename, Code);
  auto File = setupCodeComplete(ci, Filename, Line, Column);
  clang::SyntaxOnlyAction Act;
  if (Act.BeginSourceFile(ci, File )) {
    Act.Execute(); // segfault
    Act.EndSourceFile();
  }
};

auto runExample = [](auto& ci){
  runCodeCompleterAt(ci, "test.cpp", "std::cou", 1, 7);
}
```

I appreciate any hints.

Comment: [OT] std::move in `return std::move(MB);` should be removed. (it only forbid RVO).

Comment: [OT] MB is a unique_ptr, shoudn't i be explicit about moving ownership ?

Comment: Look at [when-should-stdmove-be-used-on-a-function-return-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856344/when-should-stdmove-be-used-on-a-function-return-value)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is although you can add `llvm::MemoryBuffer` into `clang::FrontendInputFile`, `clang::SyntaxOnlyAction` doesn't accept such input, it will cause assertion failure. As I said in [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37260534/how-to-use-clang-compilerinstance-for-completion/37372681#37372681), you may want to look into `ASTUnit::CodeComplete` in `lib/Frontend/ASTUnit.cpp`.

Actually you can use `remappedFiles` to link a filename with a buffer:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned Line = 2;
    unsigned Column = 13;
    clang::CompilerInstance ci;
    llvm::StringRef codeStr("void MyFoo() {}\nint main() {My return 0}");

    // Just a dummy filename, the file even doesnt' exist.
    std::string Filename("virtualFile.cpp");
    std::unique_ptr<llvm::MemoryBuffer> MB(llvm::MemoryBuffer::getMemBuffer(codeStr, Filename));

    // Create diagnostics and target
    ci.createDiagnostics();
    std::shared_ptr<clang::TargetOptions> to = std::make_shared<clang::TargetOptions>();
    // clang -v
    //to->Triple = "x86_64-pc-win32";
    //to->Triple = "x86_64-apple-darwin";
    to->Triple = "x86_64-apple-darwin15";
    ci.setTarget(clang::TargetInfo::CreateTargetInfo(ci.getDiagnostics(), to));

    // Create language options
    clang::LangOptions &lo = ci.getLangOpts();
    lo.CPlusPlus = true;
    lo.CPlusPlus11 = true;

    // Create code complete options
    clang::CodeCompleteOptions cco;
    cco.IncludeMacros = 0;
    cco.IncludeCodePatterns = 1;
    cco.IncludeGlobals = 1;
    cco.IncludeBriefComments = 1;

    // Set up the callback, I will go back to this callback class later
    auto pCustomCodeCompleteConsumer = new CustomCodeCompleteConsumer(cco);
    ci.setCodeCompletionConsumer(pCustomCodeCompleteConsumer);

    // Set up code complete postions & file
    // Until now I didn't find a way to pass in a string rather than a file name
    clang::FrontendOptions& frontendOpts = ci.getFrontendOpts();
    frontendOpts.CodeCompletionAt.FileName = Filename;
    frontendOpts.CodeCompletionAt.Line = Line;
    frontendOpts.CodeCompletionAt.Column = Column;
    frontendOpts.Inputs.push_back(clang::FrontendInputFile(Filename, clang::InputKind::IK_CXX));

    clang::PreprocessorOptions& preprocessorOpts = ci.getPreprocessorOpts();
    preprocessorOpts.clearRemappedFiles();
    preprocessorOpts.addRemappedFile(Filename, MB.release());

    // Execute
    clang::SyntaxOnlyAction Act;
    if (Act.BeginSourceFile(ci, ci.getFrontendOpts().Inputs[0])) {
        Act.Execute();
        Act.EndSourceFile();
    }
}
```

The output contains`COMPLETION: 50 Decl : MyFoo : [#void#]MyFoo()`.

I get this answer from code segment

```
  PreprocessorOpts.clearRemappedFiles();
  PreprocessorOpts.RetainRemappedFileBuffers = true;
  for (const auto &RemappedFile : RemappedFiles) {
    PreprocessorOpts.addRemappedFile(RemappedFile.first, RemappedFile.second);
    OwnedBuffers.push_back(RemappedFile.second);
  }
```

in `ASTUnit::CodeComplete`.

I believe you may want to read `AugmentedCodeCompleteConsumer` to make use of those completion hints.